# Why "plus" sign for ID resources in referred names in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I couldn't come up with a better title for this question, so please feel free to amend it if you can.

So here is my question. I decided to write a small app for myself and along the way I am also trying to learn Android Development better. I know why there is a [`+`(plus)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id) sign in the `android:id` attribute as it means "creating a new id resource". But I don't know why Android needs to put `+` in the ones used for referencing such as below:

Here I have two buttons named `StartButton` and `StopButton` and as they are new resources, the `android:id` contains `+`:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/StartButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:onClick="StartButton_OnClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/StopButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/StartButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/StartButton"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    tools:context=".CallerBlockerActivity"
    android:onClick="StopButton_OnClick" />
```

But why `android:layout_alignTop` contains `+` puzzles me since `id/StartButton` is defined when `@id/StopButton` reaches it. Can some one please explain the necessity of this syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter either way -- there only needs to be a + for the first reference to an ID. If the ID is already defined, the + is ignored anyway. You could place a + before every reference in the XML if you wanted to, and everything would work as expected. It's only necessary for the first reference, though.

Comment: This is auto-generated code by Android Designer so it should have meaning if it does it this way I believe.

Comment: It should have, but trust me it doesn't in this case. You can try it yourself both ways -- there is no difference. I would imagine it's just for precaution since you might rearrange items later.

Comment: What I am thinking is it is there for pre-cautious reasons. So if that resource is not defined, if there is no such resource, than Android will simply create a new resource.

Comment: Well it seems we are thinking of the same thing! :)

Comment: well What I think `+` is only for precautions in `android:layout_alignTop....`. As if `StopButton` definition is written above the `StartButton`. And `+` sign is missing then there will be an error.